# Convert Drive image to base 64 encoding for upload using google app script

Tags: google-apps-script, base64

Get file from drive and convert it to base64 format using google app script.
I have used getFileById method from DriveApp.
I got file size, file name and mime type. but am not able to get the image content to encode to base 64.

```
fileId = '1kLLkY_0TYs01o32q26uPQ_ndzaOQRmhi';
var file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);
Logger.log(file);
var docName = file.getName();
var docSize = file.getSize();
var docType = file.getMimeType();

var docImg = Utilities.base64Encode(file.getBlob());
Logger.log(docImg);


fileId = '1kLLkY_0TYs01o32q26uPQ_ndzaOQRmhi';
var file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);
Logger.log(file);
var docName = file.getName();
var docSize = file.getSize();
var docType = file.getMimeType();

var docImg = Utilities.base64Encode(file.getBlob());
Logger.log(docImg);
```

I expected to get exact image to convert base 64 format, then only i can upload to my server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Google Apps Script reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#base64Encode(Byte)) specifies that

> the method `Utilities.base64Encode()` generates a base-64 encoded
>   string from a byte array.

Thus, **you need to get your blob as bytes** first, before encoding it:

```
var docImg = Utilities.base64Encode(file.getBlob().getBytes());
```